# cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Class, Class>.ValueCollection to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

I am trying to return a generic ValueCollection as an ICollection. From he MSDN docs it says that Dictionary.ValueCollection implements the ICollection interface. For some reason though, I am receiving an error when it needs to cast the ValueCollection as an ICollection. This is the code sample and below it is the error I am receiving.

```
public ICollection<T> GetAllComponents<T>() where T : Component
    {
        Dictionary<Entity, Component>.ValueCollection retval = null;

        if(!this.componentEntityDatabase.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            Logger.w (Logger.GetSimpleTagForCurrentMethod (this), "Could not find Component " + typeof(T).Name + " in database");
            return new List<T>();
        }

        Dictionary<Entity, Component> entityRegistry = this.componentEntityDatabase [typeof(T)];

        retval = entityRegistry.Values;

        return (ICollection<T>)retval;

    }
```

error:

```
Cannot convert type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Entity,Component>.ValueCollection' to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>
```

Am I doing this wrong? or is there an alternative way to accomplish this without copying the values from the Dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, `ValueCollection` implements `ICollection<Component>`, not `ICollection<T>`.  even though `T` must be a `Component`, you don't guarantee that all of the values will be of type `T`.

Here's a few choices:

- Change the return type to `ICollection<Component>`
- <strike>If all of the values in the dictionary returned from `componentEntityDatabase` are of type `T`, change `entityRegistry` to `Dictionary<Entity, T>`</strike>
- Use `OfType` to return *only* the values that are of type `T`:

  ```
  retval = entityRegistry.Values.OfType<T>().ToList();  // turn into a List to get back to `ICollection<T>`
  ```

**Edit**

After looking more closely, you're going to have to limit the results to just objects of type `T`.  Using `OfType` is probably the safest way to do this.